# YouTube getting started quota

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently getting this error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).". Details: "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).">

Even though I have not made 10000 requests.

I have only made 40 requests in about 1 hour so I'm unsure why this is happening.

Comment: This is the answer your question: [How to improve my YouTube video upload data v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62476289/8327971).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469228/the-request-cannot-be-completed-because-you-have-exceeded-your-quota)